# Hibernate/JPA equals() and hashCode() with Lazy loaded Business Identifier

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, lazy-loading, equals

I'm wondering how to write a correct equals() and hashCode() for Hibernate Entities which have a Lazy Loaded ManyToOne relation to another Entity which is important as a business key. Note, that I already read [the Hibernate documentation on this topic](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/EqualsandHashCode) and I know I must/should not use the object id.

To clarify, here an example:

```
public class BusinessEntity implements Serializable
{
    //for simplicity, here just the important part
    private String s;

    @ManyToOne(fetch= FetchType.LAZY )
    private ImportantEntity anotherEntity;

    @Override
    public boolean equals( Object obj )
    {
       //Here I would like to call something like
       // (obj.getAnotherEntity.getName.equals(getAnotherEntity.getName) && obj.getS().equals(getS());

       return true;
    }
}
```

Of course this is just a simplified example. But I hope I could explain my scenario. Has someone tried something like that before? I did not find anything regarding to this topic.

Comment: Using the object id is OK is some circumstances -- for example if new BusinessEntity objects won't be getting created. Also you might just be able to use the default equals/hashcode depending on how your session are handled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For simplicity I have skipped null-safety code. But the idea is to create
additional property which will persist entity name and will not expose it to the outside world

```
public class BusinessEntity implements Serializable
{
    //for simplicity, here just the important part
    private String s;

    @ManyToOne(fetch= FetchType.LAZY )
    private ImportantEntity anotherEntity;

    private String anotherEntityName;

    @Override
    public boolean equals( Object obj )
    {
        if(BusinessEntity.class.isAssignableFrom(obj.getClasS())){  
         BusinessEntity other =  (BusinessEntity)obj;
         return other.anotherEntityName.
                equals(this.anotherEntityName) && 
                other.s.equals(this.s);

        }
       return true;
    }
    public void setAnotherEntity(ImportantEntity ie){
        anotherEntityName= ie.getName();
        anotherEntity = ie;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think i got the idea. But shouldn't this be a @Transient field?

Comment: Well if it was transient  you would have to initiate it on entity load using @PostLoad callback and if it is not transient you dont have to fatch anotherEntity just to calculate hashCode() and equals() so it is just a optimization approach but produces data redundancy (you need to decide what is best for you)

Answer (score 3):

In the equals you should use instanceof to compare types and the getters of the properties that you need to include.

instanceof is used because of the proxy classes that hibernate uses and the getters are used to enable lazy loads.